# Conditional CSS overriding normal CSS

Tags: jquery, css, primefaces

```
if ($('.ui-tabs-left ul li').length > 10) {
        $(".ui-tabs-left ul").css("height", "auto");
}
```

With the code above, I am using Primefaces 5.2, and Tabview with Tabs Orientation at the left. I generate dynamic tabs, and when the tab count exceeds 10, the above code set the background height of the tabs `auto`.

That is working fine. But when I switch over to all the other pages, the height is getting overridden. Sometimes it results in an incorrect background height in other pages, but at other times it works fine. That is, there’s a problem but I am unable to reliably reproduce it.

Any suggestions on how I can further troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: is your js getting called on every page

Comment: do you see any error in the console while changing the tab?

Comment: Keep in mind, that `$('.ui-tabs-left ul li')` will target all tabs on the page including those being hidden. Since you say that you generate dynamic tabs, could it be possible that you have some tabs on the page that are generated but hidden? Open the console using `<F12>`. Once the page fully loads, copy `$('.ui-tabs-left ul li').length` into the console and see how many tabs it finds on the page.